# How to navigate between Fragment through dynamically created Button?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm sorry for my bad English.

Hello, I'm creating an app that when you click a Button it will create a Button and when clicked, it will navigate to another Fragment. I've already tried making it but for some reason when I click the dynamically created Button, I was sent to the home screen.

Here's my code:

FirstFragment.kt:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding : FragmentFirstBinding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)

        binding.button.setOnClickListener {
            makeButton(senjata1)
        }

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun makeButton(Senjata : Senjata) {
        val dynamicButton = Button(activity)

        dynamicButton.layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )

        dynamicButton.text = Senjata.name

        dynamicButton.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment)
        }
        Senjata.targetView.addView(dynamicButton)
    }

}
```

navigation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/navigation"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main"
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="com.example.prototipesejarah.MainFragment"
        android:label="MainFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_mainFragment_to_firstFragment"
            app:destination="@id/firstFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_first"
        android:id="@+id/firstFragment"
        android:name="com.example.prototipesejarah.FirstFragment"
        android:label="FirstFragment" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_firstFragment_to_secondFragment"
            app:destination="@id/secondFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/secondFragment"
        android:name="com.example.prototipesejarah.SecondFragment"
        android:label="SecondFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_second" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: >  I've already tried making it but for some reason when I click the dynamically created Button, I was sent to the home screen.
Your question is about navigation and you're using the navigation library. So you should post your navigation graph, as that's likely where the issue is.

Comment: Provide your nav graph.

Comment: I've posted the nav graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to add the layout element in the destination's layout file.

fragment_second.xml:

Before:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
</LinearLayout>
```

After:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```